# Как a babel добавить поддержку синтаксиса export * from "./another_file.js"?

Tags: javascript, babel

Как a babel добавить поддержку синтаксиса `export * from "./another_file.js"` ?

Подскажите какой плагин добавить? Четыре часа гугления не помогают

Comment: Естественно вот эти два плагина не работают  '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',  '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',

Comment: А какой пресет стоит?

Comment: @babel/preset-env  без каких либоо настроек, и nodejs 12